# \mathbb R is not showing in reference, bibtex

Tags: bibtex

Hi I am using the following but in reference $\mathbb R^d$ is not showing for the bibtex file.

```
@inproceedings {leguesdron1989marche,
  title = {Walk al {\ 'e} atoire on the semi-group of contractions of $$ \ backslash $ mathbb $ \ {$ R $ \} $ \ ^ {} d $. Case of random walking on $$ \ backslash $ mathbb $ \ {$ R $ \} $ \ _ + $ with elastic shock {\ 'e} in z {\' e} ro},
  author = {Leguesdron, Jean-Pierre},
  booktitle = {Annales de IHP Probabilit {\ 'e} s et statistics},
  volume = {25},
  number = {4},
  pages = {483--502},
  year = {1989}
}
```

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Marche+al%C3%A9atoire+sur+le+semi-groupe+des+contractions+de&btnG=

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,oneside, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,graphics,float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, bottom=0.1 mm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\llap{\thetitle\quad}}
\setlength{\parskip}{4pt} 
\setlength{\parindent}{4pt}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
```

anf for reference:
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Main}

Thanks for any help to fix my latex packages etc or suggesting some packages to include to fix the problems.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the code `$$ \ backslash $ mathbb $ \ {$ R $ \} $ \ _ + $`? It should be something similar to `$\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and  `$\mathbb{R}_{+}$` for the two math items in that title.

Comment: hey I have just copied the bibtex file, did nothing.

Comment: Unless the bibtex code is from a source you really trust, you always need to manually check that the bibtex data is formatted correctly. I've even found errors in the formatting for bibtex taken from MathSciNet (MathSciNet is a commercial databse).

Comment: The whole entry you've pulled is messed up *catastrophically*. And it's not just the math part. For one, why is a mixture of French and English given?? For sure, the title field should be `title = "Marche aléatoire sur le semi-groupe des contractions de $\mathbb{R}^d$. Cas de la marche aléatoire sur $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ avec choc élastique en zéro",`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Scholar is known to produce garbled BibTeX references. I get

```
@inproceedings{leguesdron1989marche,
  title={Marche al{\'e}atoire sur le semi-groupe des contractions de $$\backslash$mathbb $\{$R$\}$\^{} d $. Cas de la marche al{\'e}atoire sur $$\backslash$mathbb $\{$R$\}$ \_+ $ avec choc {\'e}lastique en z{\'e}ro},
  author={Leguesdron, Jean-Pierre},
  booktitle={Annales de l'IHP Probabilit{\'e}s et statistiques},
  volume={25},
  number={4},
  pages={483--502},
  year={1989}
}
```

which should definitely be fixed:

```
@inproceedings{leguesdron1989marche,
  title={Marche al{\'e}atoire sur le semi-groupe des contractions de {$\mathbb{R}^d$}. {Cas} de la marche al{\'e}atoire sur {$\mathbb{R}_+$} avec choc {\'e}lastique en z{\'e}ro},
  author={Leguesdron, Jean-Pierre},
  booktitle={Annales de l'IHP Probabilit{\'e}s et statistiques},
  volume={25},
  number={4},
  pages={483--502},
  year={1989}
}
```

I'm not sure why you're trying to translate the title.

Note that `{Cas}` should be braced in order that BibTeX doesn't change the case; the same for `{$\mathbb{R}$}`.

Answer (score 3):

It look like you've got a bunch of badly formed math markup in the title. Try doing this instead

```
title = {Walk al {\ 'e} atoire on the semi-group of contractions of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Case of random walking on $\mathbb{R}_+$ with elastic shock {\ 'e} in z {\' e} ro},
```

(Although looking at the original title, it's more than just the math that's gotten garbled).

Comment: I think it should be `al{\'e}atoire` (French for "random"), `z{\'e}ro}` (no translation needed, right?), and `Probabilit{\'e}s`.

Comment: The whole title is messed up. I just fixed the math. His version of the title switches to English halfway through as well and doesn't match the linked article.

Comment: You're absolutely right.